# Java - Is the Point class's hashCode() method any good, or should I override it and write my own?

Tags: java, hashcode, point, hashset

Is there any way to actually see the source code of standard java classes by the way? I'm making a hash table of points (`HashSet<Point>`) and I want to make sure that it will hash well, but I can't see what Point's hashCode() method actually looks like, so I don't know how good it really is. Can anyone help me? Should I override it? And if so, is there an easy way to do this without creating a whole new java file/class?

Comment: I don't know about other IDEs, but in Eclipse you can attach the source code to Java's library. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Select the JARs -> Source Attachment. Navigate to the src.zip you get with your JDK (or following Jon Skeet's link) and voilà.

Comment: The source is located in `src.zip` within your JDK directory.

Comment: You can also google > java awt point source and the first search result will most likely be the complete source code for the class :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're searching for the `hashCode()` of `java.awt.Point`, it is defined in `java.awt.geom.Point2D`.

```
/**
 * Returns the hashcode for this <code>Point2D</code>.
 * @return      a hash code for this <code>Point2D</code>.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    long bits = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getX());
    bits ^= java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getY()) * 31;
    return (((int) bits) ^ ((int) (bits >> 32)));
}
```

Note that the question *"Will it hash well?"* is hard to answer, it depends primarily on usage pattern.

You can access the source code of nearly all *"standard Java classes"*, just search for the `src.zip` file in your JDK installation directory (or use an IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans and click F3 on the class name).

Comment: This is, by the way, not a bad hash code implementation, as it goes.  Not what I would call secure against a deliberate attack, but perfectly good for everyday use.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: Note that I did not say it is bad, I was referring to Tim's question _"I want to make sure that it will hash well"_. I believe that one shouldn't touch the predefined behaviour, they should be generally enough. In my experience, after profiling it always boils down to some other part of the code that cause the bottleneck.

Comment: Word of warning to all those using this for identification. Hash collisions are a reality... E.g. pastebin.com/6wM3W3Wv

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to actually see the source code of standard java classes by the way?

Yes - I believe it usually comes with the JDK, in a src.zip file within your JDK directory. If it's not, then the way to get it will depend on the version of Java you're using. The full JDK 6 source is available [here](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/) for example, or JDK 7 has a separate [source code download page](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) with various options.

As for how good the hash is - why not test it with a sample of your *actual* points? There will always be the possibility of collisions, but whether or not they really occur will depend on your data. One easy way of finding out how collision-free the hash is in your case is to use a [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) - add the hash code from each point to the set, and then afterwards that will basically give you the frequency of each hash code.

To be honest, I'd *expect* the hash algorithm to be pretty reasonable for general purpose use. But testing is always a good idea if you're concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Java source code comes with the JDK in the `src.zip` file. **Note that `Point`'s `hashCode()` is defined in its parent, `java.awt.geom.Point2D`.**

If you decide the existing implementation is not up to your standards, you might prefer to override the `hashCode` method using an anonymous class, defined "on the fly":

```
Point myPoint = new Point() {

    public int hashCode() {
        // custom implementation
    }

}; // <-- note required semicolon
```

This way you won't have to create a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and search for `Java SE 6 JDK Source Code`.  Download the source and read it for yourself.  I doubt you'll do better but it's good to be skeptical.