# HashMap get value of object that is "equal" but different hash?

Tags: java

I've got a `HashMap<Point, T>` data structure which holds several points that are mapped to other instances of the class `T`. This map is given some default values when my class is instantiated like this:

```
T t1 = new T();
T t2 = new T();
Point p1 = new Point(0, 1);
Point p2 = new Point(0, 2);

HashMap<Point, T> map = new HashMap<Point, T>();
static {
    map.put(p1, t1);
    map.put(p2, t2);
}
```

In my code, I will be receiving events that contain an `x` and an `y` value. When I receive one of these events I'm trying to create a new `Point` object with the `x` and `y` that is passed and then retrive the value from the map like this:

```
Point p = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY); // Assume (x, y) = (0, 1) (p1)
if(p.equals(p1)    
    T t = map.get(p);
```

Although `p` is equal to `p1` in this case (with (x, y) = (0, 1) I am getting a `null` value back from the `map`. I assume that is because the `hashCode()` method in `Point (Point2D)` uses something else than `equals` to calculate an unique hash, which it should to prevent collisions.

My question is: *How can I retrive the value from the `map` using the new instance `p`? Is there another data structure that would fit the use case?*

I guess I could use `toString()` or some other mapping like `HashMap<String, T>` or perhaps I would extend the `Point` class and `Override` the `hashCode()` method to suit my purposes. These ways feel "hacky" though, if there is a cleaner way I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Hashcodes need not be unique. Collisions are normal. equals() method is used to disambiguate.

Comment: do you have the implementation of Point?

Comment: can you give us the full code or atleast the main method?

Comment: @kabram Hashcodes need to be unique of course. I'm wondering is if there is another data structure that would suit my need?

Comment: @evanwong It's the regular java class Point that extends Point2d

Comment: @span: no, hashCodes don't need to be unique.

Comment: @JBNizet True, but they usually are. Sort of not what I'm trying to ask though :P

Comment: How are you using add method to add a value to hashmap??And what are you trying to do with the static block?

Comment: Sorry Renjith, it's supposed to be "put", not "add". Fixed it. The static block is just for initialization. I do not have the complete code sample with me at the moment so I just wrote up the quick essentials of the problem I was facing.

Comment: @span, by definition, they are not unique. They only map to a large range. Hashcodes are not unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29),

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

It appears that in your case two `Point` objects are equal (as per the `equals` method) but their hash codes are different. This means that you need to fix your `equals` and `hashCode` functions to be consistent with each other.

Comment: Thanks, but Point is the Point in the Java API so if I'm to fix it I need to extend it. Also, why would they go against their own recommendation?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: Point is Java 1.0; it predates the Joshua Bloch "Effective Java" recommendations for how to properly override equals and hashCode by almost a decade.  That's why it's not consistent with today's best practice.

Comment: That would explain a lot. Thanks! Will override I guess :/

Comment: @span That's not a recommendation, it is a requirement. I think that the version from the latest JDK overrides the hash code as well (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9251961/335858) for a code snippet showing how it is done). There may be a problem with comparison of values of type `double`, though.

Comment: Unless you need your `Point` object to tie into existing Java libraries, you may find it better to roll your own `Point` class that does exactly what you want, rather than extend Java's class.

Comment: I agree with dimo414.  Write your own - it's not that much effort.  Overriding buys you nothing of value that I can see, unless you pass those values to libraries that require the JDK class.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try writing a self contained example like the follow we can run

```
Map<Point, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        map.put(new Point(i, j), "(" + i + "," + j + ")");

// test the map
int misMatches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        String expected = "(" + i + "," + j + ")";
        String text = map.get(new Point(i, j));
        if (!expected.equals(text)) {
            System.err.println("Expected <" + expected + "> but got <" + text + ">");
            misMatches++;
        }
    }
System.out.println(misMatches + " mis-matches found.");
```

prints

```
0 mis-matches found.
```

Comment: Very strange, I will look into this. Are you using Java 6 or 7 for that?

Comment: I'm getting same results here in my home environment, I will try this tomorrow at the other environment to investigate further.

Comment: I was using Java 8, but I wouldn't expect it to be any different. Point is a very old class. (more than 10 years)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is any problem with equals() or hashcode() of Point class.Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<Point, Integer> map = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();
        Point p1 = new Point(0, 1);
        Point p2 = new Point(0, 2);
        map.put(p1,1);
        map.put(p2,2);
        Point p = new Point(0, 1);
        if(p.equals(p1)){
            System.out.println(map.get(p));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not");
        }



    }
```

It is producing the correct result.

I guess you are not initialising the map properly.

Answer (score 1):

hashCode() should use the same attributes as equals() in order to be consistent.

See also: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: So you're recommending to extend Point or Point2d and override hashCode() if I want to use a map? No other way?

Comment: Since I'm only using Java SE classes for this I'm a bit confused to why it's not working and only returning null.